How to Predict Remaining Lifetime or Replacement Probability of Machine Parts?
I am diluting and abstracting away some details to protect the client, but the basic idea like this.
Context
An authorised vehicle service centre run by a company, something like Audi, where vehicles come for regular maintenance and checkup, and their parts (if needed) are replaced. There are about 2000 different parts, which the service centre has to stock. Overstocking means rising inventory cost, understocking means delay in servicing (order the parts to be shipped from overseas).
Modelling Objective
Accurate (at least as accurate as possible) prediction of how many of each parts do I need in the coming (~30 days). I don't need a day-by-day break up, of course.
Data Available

Mapping of which parts fit into which Audi model
How many Audis (of each model) are running around in the city, what are their daily mileages?
Historical transaction data going back a few years, like, on what day car 4948A needed its fuel injection pump replaced, what was the gap from the previous replacement of the same part on that car, how many miles did it drive meanwhile etc.

We can, of course, process the data to daily demands of various parts going back a few years, which is the point of the next section.
Initial Approach
Cast this as a time series forecasting problem, by calculating how many fuel injection pumps we needed every day, then forecast next 30 days, standard supervised learning, with some feature engineering.
But it's not helpful because many parts are rarely used, hence on most days, the target column is zero.
Modifications
Tried models like Croston, TSB etc. which I read were useful for intermittent demand forecasting, but because of the rarity and volatility, all these models are becoming basically averaging engine, in spite of the long span of historical data. As an example, a part was needed thrice over a period of 18 months, so the model ends up predicting something .16 for all months over the validation period. No use.
Incomplete Idea
Instead of a forecasting problem, can I see the problem of which (how many) specific car will need the fuel injection pump replaced in the next 30 days? Use the historical and daily usage data to predict that?
Questions
Any idea on how should the training/test sets look like? Basically, what should be the

feature columns
label column
loss function
reporting metric over test/validation periods

Even if not concrete answers, some ideas around problems of this nature, or any tutorial, paper or library (python) that can deal with this, will be appreciated.
Assumptions

All Audi cars in the city always get serviced through the authorised service centre, i.e. their entire history is captured in the data

